# How to get observed bitrate from Google's ExoPlayer

Tags: java, android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I'm playing an HLS file using ExoPlayer and i'm trying to get the actual observed bitrate (not the indicated bitrate).

I now there is the `onInFoListener` interface but documentation is sketchy, can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "observed" vs "indicated"?

Comment: Indicated is what appears in the manifest. Observed is the actual bitrate at which the stream is being downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing research i came up with this:

Indeed ExoPlayer comes with a `InfoListener` interface that can be used for this purpose. This is the code i wrote.

(in my implementation `mVideoPlayer` is the var name that holds my ExoPlayer instance)

on the code that prepares the player...

```
   ...
   // assigns this as InfoListener for ExoPlayer
   mVideoPlayer.setInfoListener(this);
   ...
```

Later on the InfoListener implementation ...

```
    private long mBytesLoaded = 0;
    private long mBytesLoadedSeconds = 0;
    private long mLastBytesLoadedTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onLoadStarted(int sourceId, long length, int type, int trigger, Format format, int mediaStartTimeMs, int mediaEndTimeMs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadStarted sourceId " + sourceId + " length " + length + " type " + type + " format " + format + " mediaStartTimeMs " + mediaStartTimeMs + " mediaEndTimeMs " + mediaEndTimeMs);
        if(mLastBytesLoadedTime == 0) mLastBytesLoadedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadCompleted(int sourceId, long bytesLoaded, int type, int trigger, Format format, int mediaStartTimeMs, int mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLoadCompleted sourceId " + sourceId + " bytesLoaded " + bytesLoaded + " type " + type + " format " + format + " mediaStartTimeMs " + mediaStartTimeMs + " mediaEndTimeMs " + mediaEndTimeMs);

        // log... logBytesLoadedInSeconds
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float diffInSeconds = (now - mLastBytesLoadedTime) / 1000;
        this.logBytesLoadedInSeconds(bytesLoaded, diffInSeconds); // helper function, explain bellow
        mLastBytesLoadedTime = now;
    }
```

This is that helper function that is logging how many bytes are loaded in an amount of seconds

```
    /**
     * Logs an amount of bytes loaded in an amount of seconds
     *
     * @param bytes amount of bytes loaded
     * @param seconds time in seconds that it took to load those bytes
     */
    private void logBytesLoadedInSeconds(long bytes, float seconds){
        mBytesLoaded += bytes;
        mBytesLoadedSeconds += seconds;
        if(mBytesLoadedSeconds > 0){
            double bytesPerSecond = mBytesLoaded / mBytesLoadedSeconds;
            double bitsPerSecond = bytesPerSecond * 8; // (8 bits in a byte)
            if(bitsPerSecond < mIndicatedBitrate){
                // buffer is falling behind!
                mBufferWarned = true;
            }else{
                if(mBufferWarned){
                    // buffer caught up
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, we can use all of this information to get an estimate of the observed birate...

```
    public int getObservedBitrate(){
        if(mBytesLoadedSeconds != 0){
            double bytesPerSecond = mBytesLoaded / mBytesLoadedSeconds;
            double bitsPerSecond = bytesPerSecond * 8; // (8 bits in a byte)
            Log.d(TAG," mBytesLoaded " + mBytesLoaded + " in "+mBytesLoadedSeconds+" seconds ("+(int)bitsPerSecond+" b/s indicated "+mIndicatedBitrate+" b/s) ");
            return (int)bitsPerSecond;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just use `onVideoFormatEnabled` provided by `InfoListener`? It gives you the bit rate explicitly (`format.bitrate`) as well as all the other details (frame rate, resolution, etc.).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It is still there, check https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo/player/DemoPlayer.java#L217

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez where ? I can't see anything

Comment: @maňish looks like the implementation has since changed. I will have to research this again.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but this might help other people,

```
Format format = your_exoplayer.getVideoFormat()       //returns Format
```

Now once you get the Format, you can get the trackName by following code

```
TrackNameProvider trackNameProvider = new DefaultTrackNameProvider(getResources());
trackNameProvider.getTrackName(format)          //returns track name in string format (Ex:- 640 * 360, 0.50 Mbps)
```

Comment: Is this on ExoPlayer or SimpleExoPlayer - seems like it may have gone away (from ExoPlayer) in recent versions and deprecations.

Answer (score 1):

HlsSampleSource has an EventListener with a few calls to implement. 
A few of these calls return Format objects (com.google.android.exoplayer.chunk.Format) that have an attribute 'bitrate'.

Format appears in:
onDownstreamFormatChanged
onLoadStarted
onLoadCompleted

The HlsSampleSource.EventListener can be passed during the renderer building as part of an HlsSampleSource.

http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer/hls/HlsSampleSource.html

Comment: I believe that only gets the indicated bitrate (?), see here : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/646

Comment: Seems outdated now...